# Why Jenkins deploy to container not trigger

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I am deploying a war package to Apache tomcat 8.0.52 using Jenkins post build,but Jenkins do not trigger "Deploy to Container step".The command output has no info or error information to log out,this is my build log:

```
[INFO] Assembling webapp [cqnews-cms] in [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xycq-web-ci/cqnews-cms/target/cqnews-cms-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xycq-web-ci/cqnews-cms/profile/dev] to [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xycq-web-ci/cqnews-cms/target/cqnews-cms-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xycq-web-ci/cqnews-cms/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [2158 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xycq-web-ci/cqnews-cms/target/cqnews-cms.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) > generate-sources @ cqnews-cms >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) < generate-sources @ cqnews-cms <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) @ cqnews-cms ---
[INFO] Building jar: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xycq-web-ci/cqnews-cms/target/cqnews-cms-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.559 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-18T11:07:41+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[PostBuildScript] - Executing post build scripts.
[PostBuildScript] - Executing the script /home/jenkins-bak/a.sh with parameters [].
[xycq-web-ci] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1307617786299511400.sh
+ echo aa
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The post script plugin is execute,it is using to test post Jenkins execute workflow.This is my deploy to container configuration:

[image: Jenkins deploy configuration]

Why the war package does not deploy to tomcat? And nothing to log out execute deploy step. Why would this happen?How to fix it?

Comment: In my case I just switch from jar to war in pom.xml. Check whether there is war file in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/site/target/